# OpenCV Java binds VideoCapture from file failing silently

Tags: java, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 with the supplied Windows 64bit Java jar. I've been making full use of OpenCV in my current environment up until this point.

I'm unable to open video files using the 
`VideoCapture` class however webcam feeds work just fine.

The below works as expected with `video.isOpened` returning true

```
    VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture();
    boolean result = video.open(0);
```

The below fails with `video.isOpened` returning false

```
    VideoCapture video = new VideoCapture();
    boolean result = video.open("res/hand-test-1.mp4");
```

Neither file formats seems to make a difference (These are converted, not just renamed in hope)

```
    video.open("res/hand-test-1.mp4");
    video.open("res/hand-test-1.avi");
    video.open("res/hand-test-1.wmv");
```

Location seems to matter not either.

```
    video.open("C:/hand-test-1.mp4");
    video.open("C:\\hand-test-1.mp4");
    video.open("hand-test-1.mp4");
```

Neither does garbage, no exception kicked up from OpenCV through Java either, seems to fail silently.

```
    video.open("ashdkfhkajsjdfkhaksdf");
```

PATH contains the ffmpeg directory supplied with the opencv installation,

```
    C:\dev\opencv\sources\3rdparty\ffmpeg
```

Right now I've run out of ideas, it seems like whatever I throw to the native via `video.open(String)` will return false.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tested with in C or C++ to see if the native libraries are able to open a file? Also, what settings were used to compile OpenCV? Perhaps it wasn't compiled with ffmpeg support?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with OpenCV 2.4.9. The solution that fixed things lied in setting the PATH variable to the "bin" directory of the OpenCV installation directory, for example "C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin".

Comment: I had the same problem and found that this worked (also in 2.49), but it would be helpful to know if there's a solution that doesn't require setting environment variables -- for example, a library/dll that can be loaded from java.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was fed up with "expert" suggestions like restart,reinstall, etc etc. This worked when all else failed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (also 2.4.9). I solved it by copying the opencv.dll to the bin folder and linking to it through eclipse. This can be done by:

1. copy `opencv_java249.dll` found in `/opencv/build/java/x64` to `/opencv/build/x64/vc12/bin`
2. In eclipse right click on the project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.
   Opencv should be listed, if not add it through Add external JARs. (`opencv-249.jar` and can be found at `/opencv/build/java`).
3. Click on `opencv-249.jar` -> Native Library Location -> Edit
4. Now navigate to `/opencv/build/x64/vc12/bin` and save.

OpenCV should now be able to open the files.