# OpenCV on Windows 10 can't load video file

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to learn OpenCV 3.2.0 with Java and I am having trouble loading in a video file into the program. I work on Eclipse in Windows 10. This is a snippet from the code:

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
    Mat frameHSV = new Mat();
    VideoCapture vcap = new VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\UserName\\Downloads\\video.mov");
    while(vcap.read(frame))
    {
        frameHSV = ColorBase.BGRToHSV(frame);
        displayWindow.updateFrame(frameHSV);
    }
```

When I launch this program, I only get a white window with nothing in it. I think this has something to do with this being on windows, as I tried it out on a Linux computer and it worked as intended. This means the path points to the correct location and that the code actually works.

Is this an issue with OpenCV and Paths on windows? I get no complile errors, only a white window. How is this fixed?

Comment: Can you try another video? Preferably in format different than .mov. Perhaps it's the issue of the video codecs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by following another thread on this site that I didn't find before:

[OpenCV Java binds VideoCapture from file failing silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199886/opencv-java-binds-videocapture-from-file-failing-silently)

I followed the second answer on this thread and it worked perfectly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Its either a video codec, or permission issue, can you move the file to other drive like: `D:\\video.mov` and try?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to move the file but I still got the same issue. I'm also not quite sure how the video codecs work?

Anyway, I finally solved it by following another StackOverflow thread that I didn't see before. Will answer my own question with a link to it. Thanks!