# reading rtmp streaming using OpenCV in java

Tags: java, opencv

objective:

translate a python code that makes use of opencv into java.

issue:

inability to capture rtmp stream in the java version

details:

it's a drone control base code for a 4G drone that streams its camera feed to a nodejs rtmp server. the following is its code:

```
const { NodeMediaCluster } = require('node-media-server');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const config = {
rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 600000,
    gop_cache: false,
    ping: 60,
    ping_timeout: 30
    },
http: {
    port: 8000,
    allow_origin: '*'
},
cluster: {
    num: numCPUs
}
   };

   var nmcs = new NodeMediaCluster(config)
  nmcs.run();
```

then the stream is captured by the control base (for further operations involving opencv functionalities)

in the python version code, i used

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtmp://192.168.1.12:1935/live/STREAM_NAME')
```

to read from the server on test local network.

in java , i downloaded the official opencv tutorial sample app located [here](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/03-first-javafx-application-with-opencv.html). it's a tutorial for how to use VideoCapture objects to read from one's webcam.

like i did before in python, i replaced the argument 0 (for first cam) to the rtmp url :

```
//private static int cameraId = 0;
 String cameraId = "rtmp://192.168.1.12:1935/live/STREAM_NAME";
/**
 * The action triggered by pushing the button on the GUI
 *
 * @param event
 *            the push button event
 */
@FXML
protected void startCamera(ActionEvent event)
{
    if (!this.cameraActive)
    {
        // start the video capture
        this.capture.open(cameraId);
```

this.capture.isOpened() returns false.

and no connection attempt is made to the server

can you kindly point out where did i go wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

it took me a couple of hours to realize what is wrong. the issue has been already addressed and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199886/opencv-java-binds-videocapture-from-file-failing-silently)